# jtable single column/field in a table refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using [Jtable](http://www.jtable.org/Demo/SelectingRows) for booking events. In combination with PHP, MySQL. My question is, is there a way to just reload every 10 second single column. Precisely I have something like this:

```
Checkbox  ID  Event Reservations
    +     4   ev1   22
    -     5   ev2   19
```

I would like to have the reservations column reloaded every 10 seconds, so the user that is logged in can see the changes. Now I got it working with reloading the whole table, but this is not what I really need because every user can book only 9 events and I need to have checkboxes at the left side. After reloading the whole table my checkboxes are not working as expected. So is there a way to reload just one column?  My code right now is:

```
window.setInterval(function(){      
    $('#Events').jtable('reload');                                          
}, 10000);
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around how to solve it:

First create a new field in JS like this:

```
test: {
        title: 'test',
        display: function (data) {
        var $div = $('<div id="test"">'+data.record.id+'</div>');
        return $div;
        }
},
```

Than create a function that will be run every 10 seconds and make an AJAX request:

```
function UpdateRes(){

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Actions.php?action=update',
                type: 'post',
                data: '&kiu='+$kiu,
            }).success(function(data) {
                var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(jsondata.Records, function(i, item) {
                    $('.jtable tr.jtable-data-row').each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr('data-record-key')==item.id){
                            $(this).find('div').html( item.reservations );
                        }
                    })

                });

            }); 
        }

window.setInterval(function(){      
    UpdateRes();
}, 10000);
```

Let your JSON response look like this:

```
{"Result":"OK",
"Records":
[
{"0":"111","id":"111","1":"20","reservations":"20"},
{"0":"127","id":"127","1":"20","reservations":"20"},
{"0":"133","id":"133","1":"20","reservations":"20"},
{"0":"134","id":"134","1":"20","reservations":"20"},
{"0":"135","id":"135","1":"20","reservations":"20"},
{"0":"326","id":"326","1":"20","reservations":"20"}
]}
```

And in the end in Actions.php make your query in try catch:

```
else if($_GET["action"] == "update")
{

    //Get records from database
    $result8 = mysqli_query($con,
   "SELECT l.id,(l.max-l.reserviert) as reservations 
   FROM td_res l WHERE 
   l.kiu='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["kiu"]) . "';");

    //Add all records to an array
    $rows8 = array();
    while($row8 = mysqli_fetch_array($result8))
    {
        $rows8[] = $row8;
    }

    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows8;
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```